# PHP on local files?

Tags: php

I don't have anything extra installed on my computer.  Whenever I try to include one local PHP file on another, nothing happens.  My question is if it should be working, or if I have to have some kind of server for it to work?

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried? What error message(s) do you you see?

Comment: 3. do you have php at least installed?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you obviously need a **server** for a **server** side language... Don't you think?

Have a look at PHP servers such as **[Apache](http://www.apache.org/)**, or install an all-in-one such as **[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)** or **[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)**.

At the very least, you need to install **[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php)** and run it from the command line.